# Python error: 'bool' not iterable

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a code:

```
import os
from os import listdir

for f in sorted(os.listdir("/path")):
    if f in f.startswith("20"):
        for f in sorted(os.listdir(f)):
            if f.endswith(".txt"):
                pass
            else:
                try:
                   os.system("/path/script.py %s" % f)
                except:
                   pass
```

I have received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "files_correct_phase.py", line 5, in <module>
    if f in f.startswith("20"): 
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
 code here
```

I ran it inside the python prompt and it worked fine after line 5, but when I run it as

```
python python_script.py
```

in the command line, it gives me this error. I would be grateful for any advice and/or help.

(Python version 2.7.6)

Answer (score 4):

```
if f in f.startswith("20"):
```

is not valid.  `startswith` returns a `bool` the `in` keyword trys to check for containment inside your `bool`.  That only works for iterables (which `bool` is not).  You probably want:

```
if f.startswith("20"):
```